# Why are the Kroki-generated images in my Backstage TechDocs site broken?

Tags: mkdocs, backstage

I am generating a TechDocs site for my Backstage server using the [recommended approach](https://backstage.io/docs/features/techdocs/configuring-ci-cd) with the `techdocs-cli generate` and `publish` commands in a CI/CD pipeline. I am also using the kroki plugin. My mkdocs.yaml includes the following:

```
plugins:
  - techdocs-core
  - kroki:
      DownloadImages: true
      FencePrefix: ''
      HttpMethod: POST
      ServerURL: http://localhost:8000
```

The generated .html files include links to generated images that look like `<img alt="Kroki" src="/images/kroki_generated/<file>-<hash>.svg" />`. Those svg files are present in the images/kroki_generated directory and the whole directory structure is published to an Azure storage account.

My Backstage server is deployed with the `app-backend` plugin and I'm accessing it at the root of a domain like `https://techhub.example.com/`

When I go to the page in the docs site in backstage, for example https://techhub.example.com/docs/default/component/<component name>/<document>/, the images are broken. The browser devtools are showing requests to `https://techhub.example.com/images/kroki_generated/<file>-<hash>.svg` which returns the Backstage app's home page HTML rather than retrieving the actual svg through the techdocs backend API.

How can I get the combination of TechDocs, MkDocs and the kroki plugin to work together properly?

Comment: This seems to be related to https://github.com/AVATEAM-IT-SYSTEMHAUS/mkdocs-kroki-plugin/issues/25

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a defect in the MkDocs Kroki plugin which was fixed with https://github.com/AVATEAM-IT-SYSTEMHAUS/mkdocs-kroki-plugin/pull/20